# Remove specified vertices from a graph nested dict python

Tags: python, python-3.x, graph-theory, compiler-optimization

Helle,i have a graph G represented as follow in python:

```
G=defaultdict(list,
            {'0': ['4', '5'],
             '4': ['0', '7', '5', 'root'],
             '5': ['0', '2', '7', '4', '6', 'root'],
             '1': ['7'],
             '7': ['1', '4', '5', '6'],
             '2': ['5', '6'],
             '6': ['2', '7', '5', 'root'],
             'root': ['4', '5', '6']})
```

I need to efficiently remove a set of vertices, specified by the input, from graph G especially when the graph is very large.
I tried to browse all the dict for each vertex to be removed. There are other methods more efficient?

Comment: You have described no constraints, so you could remove one vertex chosen at random and you would be done.

Comment: There are no constraints just remove given vertices.

Comment: In which case there is no better way than iterating through the data and removing vertices in the given set when they are found.  You should be able to process graphs of several thousand vertices in less than a second.

Comment: Yes, that can be done. but the problem is that I need to do this task in my script several times. Therefore, I need better way to do that

Comment: There is no better way.  What performance are you getting?

Comment: You say you need to do this several times.  On the same graph?  In this case, it may be worthwhile to pre-process your graph to represent it as an adjacency matrix.  Such a matrix will allow you to do vertex removal much faster.  If this is worthwhile depends on how many times you need to do it and how fast the pre-processing step can be completed.  You need to measure your performance before doing anything else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
LOOP R over vertices to be removed
    FIND R in dictionary
    LOOP A over vertices linked to V
        FIND A in dictionary
        REMOVE V from vertices linked to A
    REMOVE V from dictionary
```

The above depends on the performance of FIND in dictionary.  It *should* be a highly efficient binary search.  You should also implement the straightforward looping algorithm and measure the performance of both.

```
LOOP A over vertices in dictionary
    LOOP R over vertices to be removed
        IF A = R
            REMOVE A
        ELSE
            LOOP R2 over vertices to be removed
                LOOP A2 over vertices linked to A
                    IF A2 = R2
                        REMOVE A2
```